# Key to comment out the current line and keep editing it in zsh

Tags: zsh, line-editor, zle

On Bash I was using <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>#</kbd> after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to prefix a `#` to the found line and keep it in the terminal, something similar for `zsh`?

Comment: Depending on your use-case you might be interested in the zle widgets `push-line` and `push-line-or-edit`. This pushes the current command to the stack and clears the buffer. The next time the line editor starts up (e.g. the next prompt) the command is popped off the stack and put into the buffer. This is quite useful to put a longer command on hold if you need to do something before you can actually run it.

Comment: @Adaephon thank you, nice feature I didn't know about, it doesn't cover always this particular case (sometime I just use a history entry as a visual reference) but I'll give a try on the field, can't wait for the next long command :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See `man zshzle` for the `pound-insert` and `vi-pound-insert` widgets. The first will toggle a pound sign at the beginning of the buffer, the second at the beginning of the current line. Only `pound-insert` is bound by default, and then only in the `vicmd` key map, to `#`. To bind `pound-insert`, add this line to your `.zshrc`:

```
bindkey '\e#' pound-insert
```

Comment: Thank you that was easy once pointed in the right direction `bindkey '^[#' pound-insert` :-)